# How to get a list of qsub job ids through python

Tags: python, shell, qsub, torque

I have submitted a number of jobs through `qsub`. I want to get the associated job id (that which is displayed on the left hand column in `showq`) into a list in `Python`.

I am guessing I need to use `os.system` here but I am not sure what command to use.

Comment: Have you looked into this? https://code.google.com/p/py-pbs/

Comment: This link has more documentation http://pypbs.sourceforge.net/t1.html#AEN13